# Can we use queryset.first() instead of catching exception?

Tags: django, django-views, query-optimization, django-queryset

I normally use `MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).first()` instead of `MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)` when I am not entirely sure whether there is any object with `pk=1` or not.

Is it a bad practice doing so for this scenario or I need to

```
try:
  MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
  print('not found')
```

I normally do `MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).first()` for the less code.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that. You get `None` if the object does not exist. It saves hitting the database with more than one query, compared to using `.exists()`

I would call the following self-documenting without a comment, but if you think not, then comment it

```
obj = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).first() 
if obj is None:
    # no such object exists...
    ...
else
    # process obj
    ...
```

Has just occurred to me, this is a use for the "walrus" operator if you are using an up to date Python

```
if obj := MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).first() is None:
```

but not sure I prefer it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use django built-in method `get_object_or_404` this will return 404 page if object does not exits

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=pk)
```